# requesting `root` access from user to update `/etc/paths.d`

Tags: macos, installation, config, macos-catalina

my app installer uses the standard open DMG, drag to 'Applications' for installation, but I want to update `$PATH` so my app can be used from the command line.

I think the right way to do this is to call a script on the first time my application runs that creates a file `myapp` in `/etc/paths.d` with the text `/Applications/myapp/bin` followed by a newline(ascii 13):

```sh
rm /etc/paths.d/myapp
echo "/Applications/myapp/bin" > /etc/paths.d/myapp
```

currently I'm getting errors;

```sh
rm: /etc/paths.d/myapp: No such file or directory
./myapp.sh: line 2: /etc/paths.d/myapp: Permission denied
```

**I need to trigger a request for the user to type the admin password** but I'm not sure how to do that in a way this clearly inform the user what changes I am making to their system and why. (I can add it to the manual but who reads that)

Any suggestions?

PS I need to do the same on linux(hopefully similar) and Windows, but if I can get MacOS sorted hopefully I'll know where to start.

Comment: let me know if I can improve this question in the comments

Comment: I'm thinking I need to do something like `sudo rm /etc/paths.d/myapp
echo "/Applications/myapp/bin" > /etc/paths.d/myapp`

Comment: Your current problem seems to be getting root access. This is not clear when reading the title. Maybe you can improve it.

Comment: thanks @Itchy I have changed the title.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/1540038-authorizationexecutewithprivileg) is deprecated for a long time, but still present and working in macOS 11 (Big Sur / 10.16). [STPrivilegedTask](https://github.com/sveinbjornt/STPrivilegedTask/blob/master/STPrivilegedTask.m) demonstrates how to call the function in a "safe" manner - that is, to properly handle the case where the function might be removed in a future version of the OS.

Usage is something like this (error checking etc is omitted for brevity). This will create a symlink of your executable in /usr/local/bin with the name "my-app":

```
    AuthorizationRef authorizationRef;
    OSStatus err;

    const char* tool = "/bin/ln";
    char *args[] = {
        "-sf", 
        [[[NSBundle mainBundle] executablePath] UTF8String],
        "/usr/local/bin/my-app", 
        nil
    };

    AuthorizationCreate(nil, kAuthorizationEmptyEnvironment, kAuthorizationFlagDefaults, &authorizationRef);

    err = AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges(authorizationRef, tool, kAuthorizationFlagDefaults, args, nil);

    switch (err)
    {
        case errAuthorizationCanceled:
            // user cancelled prompt
            break;
        case errAuthorizationSuccess:
            // success
            break;
        default:
            // an error occurred
            break;
    }

    AuthorizationFree(authorizationRef, kAuthorizationFlagDefaults);
```

How you use that, is up to you - you could place it behind a menu item ("Install Command Line Tools") like cmake does. If you want to install this at launch time, I'd suggest prompting the user first (and allowing them the option to "don't ask me again").